# Batch/Multi rename only files with a specific number range

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have a situation where I have the following:

```
file01.ext
.
.
.
file99.ext
file100.ext
.
.
.
```

And I want to (using rename ) insert the '0' for the files 01-99 (so that they become 000-099) but not modify files larger than 100. Which expression should I use and what is a good source on learning regular expressions such as these?

On Windows I would have used Total Commander's multi rename function which has a very simple renaming syntax. Are there some good alternatives for that tool (multi-rename) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using `rename`

A generally useful tool for this type of activity is `rename` from the `perl` package.  It applies a perl substitution to the file name:

```
rename 's/file/file0/' file[0-9][0-9].ext
```

How this works:

- `s/file/file0/`

  This is a `perl` substitution command.  It replaces the occurrence of `file` in a file name with `file0`.
- `file[0-9][0-9].ext`

  This is the list of files that `rename` is to operate on.  `[0-9]` means any number from 0 to 9.  `[0-9][0-9]` means any two numbers, one following the other.

The manpage for `rename` is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html).

**Note:** This requires the `perl` version of `rename`.  There is also a [`rename` utility](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) that is part of `util-linux` but it works differently.

### Using `bash`

This approach uses a `for` loop combined with *pattern substitution*:

```
for f in file[0-9][0-9].ext; do mv "$f" "${f/file/file0}"; done
```

How it works:

- `for f in file[0-9][0-9].ext; do`

  This starts a loop over each file name that matches the glob `file[0-9][0-9].ext`.
- `mv "$f" "${f/file/file0}"`

  This renames the files using the bash's *pattern substitution*.  It replaces `file` with file0` in the file name.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the `for` loop.

This approach requires `bash` (or other advanced shell).

`bash` is the default interactive shell and this approach will work under `bash`.  Thus, this should work on the usual command line.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will look more into regular expressions as well.

Answer (score 1):

This rename with using different regex:

```bsh
rename -n 's/[^0-9](([0-9]){2})\.ext$/0$1.ext/' *
```

`[^0-9](([0-9]){2})\.ext$` Matches any non-digit`[^0-9]` followed by group of numbers with length=2 which is ends with `.ext`. So in replacement part, add a `0` and prints group of matched `$1` and then their extension.

Or alternative for regex:

```bsh
rename -n 's/[^\d](\d{2})\.ext$/0$1.ext/' *
```

`\d` matches a number.